# HorizontalScrollView fadingEdge

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, fading, edges

Im trying to add fading edges for simple HorizontalScrollView. Documentations about fadingEdge attribute:

> This attribute is deprecated and will be ignored as of API level 14 (ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH). Using fading edges may introduce noticeable performance degradations and should be used only when required by the application's visual design. To request fading edges with API level 14 and above, use the android:requiresFadingEdge attribute instead.

Ok, but this layout not showing any fading edges, too:

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="50dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        ...

    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `android:overScrollMode` attribute.

Just add

```
android:overScrollMode="always"
```

to your `HorizontalScrollView`.

> android:overScrollMode can have three values: "always", "never", "ifContentScrolls".

Comment: overScroll and fadingEdges are different things

Comment: You're right, my bad. I tested your layout here, and it's working. Maybe there's something else causing your fading edges not to show.

Comment: Actually it's kinda old question. I haven't found an answer and to solve the problem I added to `onDraw()` method of `HorizontalScrollView` my own implementation of fading edges. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal|vertical" 
android:fadingEdgeLength="10dp"
```